# There does not exist an automorphism of $\Bbb Z^2$ of order $5$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, automorphism-group

I want to show that there does not exist an automorphism of $\Bbb Z^2$ of order $5$, i.e., an element $f\in \text{Aut}(\Bbb Z^2)$ such that $f^5=\text{id}$.

Since the automorphism group of $\Bbb Z^2$ is isomorphic to the matrix group $SL_2(\Bbb Z)$, this is equivalent to showing that the group $SL_2(\Bbb Z)$ has no subgroup of order $5$, and this is indeed true (I have searched google and found that every finite subgroup of $SL_2(\Bbb Z)$ is of order a divisor of $24$).

However, I think this is making the problem harder, so I am looking for a more simple or direct approach. Any hints?

Comment: This can be done using [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap40.html#X79640F3682BDBFC1) (I suppose).

Comment: Each occurrence of "SL" should be replaced with "GL", because the determinant could be either $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang That's true. But an automorphism of ${\mathbb Z}^2$ of order $5$ would have to lie in ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$, so the solutions remain valid.

Comment: @Shaun But how might you do that? I can't see how you would set about proving that such an element does not exist.

Comment: I haven't tried it, @DerekHolt, but what I had in mind was to make use of [`ForAll(G, g -> not (g^5=One(G)));`](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap21.html#X7F06961278166671)

Comment: @Shaun But that won't work over an infinite group.

Comment: @DerekHolt Well, okay. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a good approach, when combined with linear algebra.

Suppose $M$ is a matrix in $SL_2(\Bbb Z)$ such that $M^5=I$. This means that the minimal polynomial of $M$ divides $t^5-1$. On the other hand, the characteristic polynomial of $M$ is a degree-$2$ polynomial with integer coefficients, which the minimal polynomial of $M$ also divides. In particular, every irreducible (over $\Bbb Z$) factor of the minimal polynomial of $M$ must be an irreducible (over $\Bbb Z$) factor of $t^5-1=(t-1)(t^4+t^3+t^2+t+1)$ of degree at most $2$. The only possibility is that the minimal polynomial is $t-1$ itself, which forces $M=I$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Assume by contradiction that $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ has a subgroup $H$ of order $5$.

Since $5$ is prime, $H$ is cyclic, generated by a matrix $A\in SL_2(\mathbb Z)$.

Now, since
$$A^5=I_2 \,.$$

The minimal polynomial of $A$ is a divisor of $X^5-1$. Since $A\in SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ the minimal polynomial is a monic polynomial of degree 1 or 2 with integer coefficcients. Find it.